# Kotlin: pass a reference / pointer to a function

Tags: android, pointers, kotlin, reference

For Android development I am using Kotlin. There are various buttons (buttonA, buttonB) to call the same function. The only difference is that the same function is called with different parameters (REQUEST_A, REQUEST_B). Following Code is running fine:

```
    fun standardizedFunction(requestCode: Int){ 
    ....}

    buttonA.setOnClickListener { standardizedFunction(REQUEST_A) }
    buttonB.setOnClickListener { standardizedFunction(REQUEST_B) }
```

Now the question: Is there a way to make it more elegant? like

```
   fun standardizedFunction(Object: Pointer, requestCode: Int){ 
      Object.setOnClickListener{
      ....
      }
   }

   standardizedFunction(buttonA,REQUEST_A) 
   standardizedFunction(buttonB,REQUEST_B)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make it "nicer" by using an extension method to `View` to setup the listener:

```
fun View.standardizedFunction(requestCode: Int) = setOnClickListener {
    ...
}
```

Comment: By using this, unfortunately it's not possible to do whatever you want in method block :-|

Comment: @aminography why not? Of course it depends on where it's defined, but this is a restriction to any method.

Comment: I like your approach, even it is different as I thought originally.

Comment: Do you have an idea to do it as asked in the question?

Comment: Just the same. `fun standardizedFunction(object: View, requestCode: Int`. Both methods have the same signature in _Java_, only the usage is different in _Kotlin_. Generally objects are passed by reference. A specific kind of pointer doesn't exist.